# How do I put a $cond inside my Linq query's OrderBy()?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, sorting

I recently started a project with MongoDB in C#. Im starting to learn the basics about it but today I walked into a problem which I cant seem to figure out. Im having an OrderBy() method on my collection with Linq. Im trying to order the collections based on an IF statement using the $cond aggregate function. However I get an error which says:
only fields are allowed in a $sort

Basically Ive tried anything I could find. The solution right now is to turn the IQueryable into a list, then follow up by ordering that list. But I want to order it by the server to save performance.

Right now Im calling the query and trying to order it as I said before.
This is the code that gives the error.

```
var query = collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.ReportId == 1).OrderBy(x => x.Origin == 0 ? "Test 1" : "Test 2" );
foreach(var item in query){
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

x reassembles the following class

```
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public int ReportId { get; set; }
        public int RecId { get; set; }
        public int Origin { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

Whenever I try to loop through it I get the error: only fields are allowed in a $sort

I basically want to execute the query ordered by the result inside the IF.
Right now it gets stuck when trying to execute the query.

Comment: If you want Origin 0 first and Origin 1 next, then simply use `.OrderBy(x => x.Origin)`. But I guess you actually want something else. In that case, you're probably going to need an aggregation. Explain what you actually want.

Comment: You're telling a function that sorts by a column to sort by one of two strings (which also are completely unrelated to the table). As been previously said - what do you really want?

Comment: I just realised it is indeed not explained correctly. Origin should actually be a string. In this example you could indeed just order by origin. I have multilpe object with a value of 0 or 1. Depending on the strings that gets passed I need to return a 0 or a 1 to order on. But now that I read both of your answers I just realised now that I can probably just order on the 0 or 1 as well. No idea how I missed that

Comment: when `Origin == 0` then sort by **`field1`** otherwise sort by **`field2`** 
And field must be from class property 
in your case it can be `ReportId, RecId, Origin, Name` 
please update your code based on that 

`var query = collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.ReportId == 1).OrderBy(x => x.Origin == 0 ? field1 : field2 );`